# Python QuantLib issue with TimeGrid()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quantlib

I am trying to pass the following to `ql.TimeGrid()`, but getting an error:

```
ndays = 52

step = ndays
length = ndays/252
times = ql.TimeGrid(length, step)
```

which returns:

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_TimeGrid'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    TimeGrid::TimeGrid()
    TimeGrid::TimeGrid(Time,Size)
    TimeGrid::TimeGrid(std::vector< Time,std::allocator< Time > > const &)
    TimeGrid::TimeGrid(std::vector< Time,std::allocator< Time > > const &,Size)
```

It seems like this works for some other numbers (e.g. `ndays = 53`). Can anybody explain what is going on?

Comment: What version of QuantLib and Python? On what operating system? It works for me...

Comment: QuanLib-1.20, Python -3x on Windows machine. It's strange that I am seeing this error ...

Comment: 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: It's 64 bits. Actually, when I directly input the number instead of ndays, I get an output. I will update this if I discover other new stuff.